# What is better way to work with time, using Hibernate Criteria and Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, time, criteria

I want to select entity by Time.
I have Oracle DBMS with field type DATE which contain date and time. This is my code. How to select data by Time criteria?

```
Calendar timeCal = new GregorianCalendar(0,0,0,0,0,0);
Date     timeMin = timeCal.getTime();

timeCal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
Date     timeMax = timeCal.getTime();

if (minDate != null && maxDate != null)
    criteria.add(Restrictions.between("eventDate", minDate, maxDate));

if (onDate != null) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(onDate);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.between("eventDate", onDate, calendar.getTime()));
}

if(minTime!=null&&maxTime!=null){
    /*
      How to add Restriction on eventDate field, for time only?
      if minTime is 3:00 and maxTime is 16:00, must to return
      all rows having the time part of their eventDate between 
      3:00 and 16:00, regardless of the date part
    */
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: Not implemented minTime!=null&&maxTime!=null expression

Comment: We don't know what those criteria are, and what the query should do.

Comment: Criteria should add Restriction on eventDate field, for time only.

Comment: So, if minTime is 3:00 and maxTime is 16:00, you would like to return all rows having the time part of their eventDate between 3:00 and 16:00, regardless of the date part, is that right?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find answer. Just need use sqlRestriction.

```
criteria.add(
    Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
        " NUMTODSINTERVAL(EVENT_DATE - TRUNC(EVENT_DATE), 'DAY') BETWEEN  NUMTODSINTERVAL (?,'SECOND') AND NUMTODSINTERVAL (?,'SECOND')",
        new Object[] { secondsForBegin, secondsForEnd },
        new Type[]   { StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate HQL has `hour`, `minute` and `second` functions that you can use in this particular case, so you can do this in HQL, rather than SQL.  So you'll need an HQL query instead of a Criteria object.  The HQL will look something like

```
from  tableName
where eventDate between :minDate and :maxDate
  and 3600 * hour( eventDate ) + 60 * minute( eventDate ) + second( eventDate )
      between :minSeconds and :maxSeconds
```

where you'll set the `:minSeconds` and `:maxSeconds` parameters appropriately.  Watch out for out-by-one errors with `:maxDate` too.

More information on HQL can be found at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: Query is very big for hql and data only part.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a SQL restriction to do that, or, preferrably, you'll have to create your own Criterion implementation, which will issue the appropriate SQL restriction.

Use the `org.hibernate.criterion.IlikeExpression` class as an exemple: when it's not using the PostgreSQL dialect, it generates the SQL expression `lower(columnName) like ?`, where the argument of the expression is `value.toString().toLowerCase()`.

Your criterion should generate something like `to_date(to_char(columnName, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24:MI:SS') < ?)` where the argument of your expression is your max time. (And of course, do a similar criterion for the min time)