# JPQL equivalent of numtodsinterval

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, jpql, date-arithmetic

I have an SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM G1, G2, G3 
WHERE G1.G2_ID=G2.ID AND G1.G3_ID=G3.ID 
AND  (G3.CreationTime- G2.CreationTime) > NUMTODSINTERVAL( 300, 'day' );
```

And I need JPQL form of this query. Actually I'm stuck on the NUMTODSINTERVAL part.

Comment: May be related: **1)** [What is better way to work with time, using Hibernate Criteria and Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8881087/471214) **2)** [Hibernate and date comparisons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10983167/471214)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reformulate your query e.g. this way (using [Joda-Time](http://joda.sourceforge.net/)):

```
Duration dur = Duration.standardDays(300);
DateTime dt = new DateTime(G2.KAYIT_OLUSTURMA);//Assuming G2.KAYIT_OLUSTURMA is of java.util.Date type
DateTime calc = dt.plus(dur);


SELECT * 
FROM GEBELIKTAKIP G1, GEBEBILDIRIM G2, GEBELIKSONUCU G3 
WHERE G1.GEBELIKBILDIRIM_ID=G2.ID AND G1.GEBELIKSONUC_ID=G3.ID 
AND  G3.KAYIT_OLUSTURMA > :calc
```